# android MapBox: how to draw polygon above layer?

Tags: mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

My Mapbox have onelayers, I tried to add a Marker(by draw a polygon) in front.

However, when the Marker overlapped with the layer, Marker is always under of the layer. This is my source code. Is there a way put Marker(polygon) in front?

```
fun drawMarker(lat:Double, lon:Double){
if(null != curBluedot)
  mapboxMap.removePolygon(curBluedot!!)
if(null != mapboxMap)
curBluedot=  mapboxMap.addPolygon(generatePerimeter(
  LatLng(lat,  lon),
  0.0005,
  1000)!!)
  }




private fun loadStyle(featureCollection: FeatureCollection) {
mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.Builder()
  .fromUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
) {

  it.addSource(GeoJsonSource("symbol", featureCollection))
  it.addLayer(FillExtrusionLayer("symbol", "symbol")
    .withProperties(
      iconAllowOverlap(true),
      iconIgnorePlacement(true),
      iconImage("icon"),
      iconAnchor(ICON_ANCHOR_CENTER),
      fillExtrusionColor(Color.RED),

      //fillExtrusionColor(Color.LTGRAY)
      fillExtrusionHeight(1.5f),
      fillExtrusionBase(1.0f),
      fillExtrusionOpacity(1.0f)
    ))
}}






private fun generatePerimeter(centerCoordinates: LatLng, radiusInKilometers: Double, numberOfSides: Int): PolygonOptions? {
val positions: MutableList<LatLng> = ArrayList()
val distanceX = radiusInKilometers / (111.319 * Math.cos(centerCoordinates.latitude * Math.PI / 180))
val distanceY = radiusInKilometers / 110.574
val slice = 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides
var theta: Double
var x: Double
var y: Double
var position: LatLng
for (i in 0 until numberOfSides) {
  theta = i * slice
  x = distanceX * Math.cos(theta)
  y = distanceY * Math.sin(theta)
  position = LatLng(centerCoordinates.latitude + y,
    centerCoordinates.longitude + x)
  positions.add(position)
}
return PolygonOptions()
  .addAll(positions)
  .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
 }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem using "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.Symbol" rather than using Polygon